# Does inline assembly in MS C++ require something like volatile to prevent optimizer meddling

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I know that when using inline assembler with GCC you can decorate the assembly sections with the keyword `volatile` to keep the optimizer from moving things around.

Is there a similar thing in Microsoft C++, or does the optimizer leave inline code alone by default?

Comment: I cannot find documentation about what MS C++ will do in optimizing inline assembler. However, the lack of 'interface' declarations (like GCC's constraints) and the vague statement that register contents are saved before entering an inline asm block indicate that for MS inline asm is completely opaque and hence will not be optimized away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option, but the optimizer will not do any attempts to optimize the inline assembly.

If anything, it will use *less* optimizations on the surrounding code as it doesn't analyze the exact effects of the assembly.

Comment: It will not optimize *inside* the assembler code, but the question is if it will optimize the code away, like GCC does when it sees no application-visible effect from the asm *and* that asm is not `volatile`.

Comment: @JimmyB - No, it will not do anything like that.